# how to recursively remove files from one folder if its file name doesn't appear in another folder

Tags: command-line, files

I have two folders where one contains txt files and the other .jpg files with the exact name. However, txt files are much more than jpg files.

```
folder_1/00.txt
folder_1/01.txt 
folder_1/02.txt 
folder_1/03.txt 
folder_1/04.txt
```

---

```
folder_2/00.jpg
folder_2/01.jpg 
folder_2/02.jpg
```

Here, I need to remove `03.txt` and `04.txt` because these names don't appear in folder_2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

```bsh
$ for file in folder_1/*.jpg; do 
    fileName="${file##*/}"
    [[ -e folder_2/${fileName/.txt/.jpg} ]] || echo rm -- "$file"
done
rm -- folder_1/03.txt
rm -- folder_1/04.txt
```

The `for` loop iterates over all non-hidden files and directories in `folder_1` whose name ends in `.jpg`, saving each as `$file`. Next, `fileName="${file##*/}"` sets the variable `$fileName` to the value of `$file` with everything until the last `/` removed, which means it will be the file's name without the directory. Finally, with `[[ -e folder_2/${fileName/.txt/.jpg} ]] || echo rm -- $file`, we check if there is a file in `folder_2` with the same name but a `.txt` extension and, if not, `echo rm -- "$file"`. If this does what you want, remove the `echo` and run again to actually delete the files:

```bsh
for file in folder_1/*.jpg; do 
    fileName="${file##*/}"
    [[ -e folder_2/${fileName/.txt/.jpg} ]] || rm -- "$file"
done
```

The `--` in `rm -- "$file"` isn't necessary here but is a good habit to have: it ensures that anything after the `--` is not parsed as an option to `rm`, therefore allowing the command to also work on file names starting with an `-`.